# Save state to the disk at abrupt bitcoind shutdowns

Tags: bitcoind

I have a bitcoind running, and after new blocks being synced, sometimes I kill it(without stop command).

Next time, when I start it, it goes through already synced blocks.

Is there any way to force bitcoind keep the state on a hard drive after accepting each new block?

Answer (score 1):

I think bicoind save the state of the last block because it can access to DB and read the last block stored into DB.

also, I have noted when running bitcoind, it runs some previous bock (I don't know the motive)
This is the log of the bitcoind

```
2019-08-22T10:51:33Z init message: Rewinding blocks...
2019-08-22T10:51:36Z init message: Verifying blocks...
2019-08-22T10:51:36Z Verifying last 6 blocks at level 3
```

ps: If you kill the process bitcoind without stop command you can corrupt some file blk and inside it, the client bitcoin can store trash data